# Android callback won't run again after app onStop/OnResume

Tags: android, firebase, interface, callback, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class that runs an asynchronous call to Firestore.  I've implemented an interface and callback so I can get the data outside of the class.  The problem I'm having is that when I minimize/reopen the activity the callback stops receiving data.  I tested the Firestore call itself, and data is definitely being retrieved.  It just seems that the callback stops passing data from the Firestore get() to the Activity.

Here's my class:

```
public class FirebaseGetBooks {

//firebase objects
private FirebaseFirestore mDbase;

private Activity activity;

private String groupID;

//default constructor
public FirebaseGetBooks() {
}

public FirebaseGetBooks(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;

    //firebase new instances
    mDbase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    FirebaseGetGroupID firebaseGetGroupID = new FirebaseGetGroupID(activity);
    groupID = firebaseGetGroupID.getGroupID();
}


public interface FirestoreCallback {
    void onCallback(List<Book> books);
}


public void readDataRTUpdate(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {
    mDbase.collection("books").whereEqualTo("groupID", groupID)
            .addSnapshotListener(activity, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (value != null) {
                        int i = 0;
                        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                            books.add(document.toObject(Book.class));
                            Log.d(TAG, "Book: " + books.get(i).toString());
                            i++;
                        }
                        firestoreCallback.onCallback(books);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Document updated.");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

And here's my callback as seen in my activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseGetbook firebaseGetBooks;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        firebaseGetBooks = new FirebaseGetBooks(this);

        firebaseGetBooks.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetBooks.FirestoreCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(List<Book> books) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Books Still Firing: " + books.toString());
                }
            }); 
    }
}
```

any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the activity-scoped form of [addSnapshotListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query).  The listener is automatically removed when the `onStop()` method of the activity passed as the first parameter is called.

If you want the listener to remain active when the activity is in the background, remove `activity` from the call to `addSnapshotListener()`.  Otherwise, move your call of `firebaseGetBooks.readDataRTUpdate()` from `onCreate()` to `onStart()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bob.  My understanding when using the activity-scoped form of addSnapshotListener() is that if onStop() is called it is removed, but should start again when we load the activity.   I know that onCreate() gets called before onStart(), but I thought it would get called since onCreate() is called.  Currently, I'm accessing data that is view related so if I put it in onStart() I'll get a null error.  Eventually I'm going to switch to a ViewModel paradigm, which will probably take care of it.

Comment: Okay, so reading more about the Activity lifecycle, it sounds like the issue is that if we minimize the app (or use the back button) and then open it up again onRestart() is called which takes us to onStart(), but in this case skips onCreate(), which is probably why the snapshotListener() isn't firing again.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes.  Suggest you add log-statements to the activity lifecycle methods to confirm your understanding of when they are called.  Putting an activity into the background (your term "minimize") will cause `onStop()` to run, but does not immediately destroy the activity.  So when you "reopen" it, `onCreate()` is not called, just `onStart()` (and others, such as `onResume()`)

Comment: Exiting an activity by the Back button does cause the activity to be destroyed. You're right about that.